# Whats wrong with this PLSQL code block

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

The code block below is not running when executed from a batch file. It just hangs (nothing happens). It sits there  for hours. I am unable to track what the problem is or how to debug this. Please help.

```
declare
v_personrefid varchar2(50);
v_hiredt date;
v_loaddt date;
v_personid number;
v1_personrefid varchar2(50);
v_seq number :=0;

cursor get_row is
select distinct personrefid from ARCHIVE_PERSON;

cursor get_row1 is
select 
personrefid, 
hiredt,
loaddt,
personid
from 
ARCHIVE_PERSON 
where 
personrefid = v_personrefid 
order by hiredt, loaddt;

begin

v_seq:=0;
open Get_row;
loop
fetch get_row into v_personrefid ;
exit when get_row%notfound;

begin

open get_row1;
loop
fetch get_row1 into v1_personrefid, v_hiredt, v_loaddt, v_personid;
exit when get_row1%NOTFOUND;

v_seq:= v_seq+1;

update ARCHIVE_PERSON 
set version = v_seq 
where 
personrefid = v1_personrefid and 
personid =  v_personid and 
hiredt = v_hiredt and 
loaddt = v_loaddt;

commit;
end loop;

v_seq:=0;

close get_row1;
end;
end loop;
v_seq:=0;
close get_row;

end;
```

Comment: maybe also try creating a log table and do inserts (autonomous) along the way.  Do this as a habit.  Much better than guessing, and you'll know where you're at in your processing.  search SO for examples of this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is that you don't have a slash `/` in your script following the `end;` statement, which would tell SQLPlus to execute the block.  If you simply have `end;` followed by nothing, SQLPlus may be waiting for more input that it will never get.

Aside from that, I'd suggest having your dba look at `V$SESSION_WAIT` while the block is running to see what your session is waiting on.

Moreover, you might try a rewrite like the following, which I think will be more efficient:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR my_cur IS
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY personrefid ORDER BY hiredt, loaddt) seq
      FROM archive_person
      FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
  FOR my_rec IN my_cur LOOP
    UPDATE archive_person SET version = my_rec.seq
      WHERE CURRENT OF my_cur;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Adding the / after the end worked. I will add the optimization too. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If that is really the entire file you need a `/` after the final `end;` to tell SQL*Plus (assuming that's what you're using to run the batch file) to execute the block. If you pasted that in to the SQL*Plus command prompt you'd see it waiting for input, displaying a line number prompt.

Comment: What else than SQL*Plus one can use in batch files ?

Comment: @user272735 - it was tagged with `plsqldeveloper`, I haven't used that so don't know if it has an option to run commands from a file, or was mis-tagged. I took it to mean having the anonymous block in an external .sql file and running it with `sqlplus [-s] @file.sql` or similar, rather than 'batch' referring to a .bat or shell script; think it's a bit ambiguous here though.